# mysql query optimisation / retrieving last record in each group

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Is there any way to optimize this mysql query?
I have about 100K rows in a table.

```
select  komentarai.* FROM (
  SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM komentarai WHERE siteid=1 GROUP BY number 
) AS tbl
INNER JOIN `komentarai` ON komentarai.id = tbl.max_id ORDER BY komentarai.added DESC LIMIT XX, 10
```

Here is an explanation of index:

```
PRIMARY <derived2> ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 3372 Using temporary; Using filesort
PRIMARY komentarai eq_ref PRIMARY,id PRIMARY 4 tbl.max_id 1 2
DERIVED komentarai ref siteid siteid 1 5695 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe precisely what you are trying to achieve ? With a data excerpt and a target result ?

Comment: Hard to figure out what you want, based on that SQL, but you should know that you can also try something like this: select * from komentarai where id = (select max(id) from komentarai ... etc...)